# SwiftUI List - Edit Row

Tags: swiftui

Is there any way to style the whole row in a List when in EditMode? i.e. a border around the whole text, delete and drag icon. How about changing the delete and drag icons?

```
                   List {
                        ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                            HStack {

                                Text(option)
                                .font(.custom("Random", size: 18))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "#000000"))
                                .lineLimit(nil)
                                .padding(.leading, 10)


                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .border(Color.black)
                            .padding()
                        }
                        .onMove(perform: move)
                        .onDelete(perform: delete)


                    }
                    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might find some benefit using ViewModifiers, see https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-viewmodifier/

A view modifier would allow you to easily just pass your editMode variable into a single modifier that modifies your row view in the list with whatever you configure as your options in the view modifier.

An example:

```
struct SomeView: View {
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
let options = ["1", "2", "3"]
var body: some View {

    List {
         ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
            RowView(string: option)
                .modifier(CustomModifier(self.editMode))
         }
     }//.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
}

struct CustomModifier: ViewModifier {
    init(_ editMode: Binding<EditMode>?) {
        self.editing = editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false
    }

    var editing: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .foregroundColor(editing ? .red : .green)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("I'm a \(self.editing ? "red" : "green") thing")
        }
    }
}
```

}

struct RowView: View {
    let string: String

```
var body: some View {
    Text(string)
}
```

}

As for changing the delete and move icons, I'm unfamiliar with that. I wasn't able to readily find a solution googling that, either sorry.

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't clear. I wanted to be able to style the entire row, which meant a border around the delete icon, text and also drag icon.

Comment: If you are wondering about color change in dark mode.User .environment(\.colorScheme, .light) // or .dark
Code to change color scheme for particular view

Answer (score 0):

You could create a border using two rectangles stacked on top of each other.
In order to make sure that the border is underneath the other information, make sure to put it before the rest of the content in your cell, all in a ZStack.[image: Two Rectangle() border]
Imagine that the first ZStack is the Cell. Also, you'd want to use maxWidth and maxHeight for the first rectangle to make sure it's filling the entire cell, and then you'd have to use geometry reader to figure out the hight and width of the cell in order to properly set the width and height of the second rectangle.
Good luck!
Note: I don't know how this would work alongside a default Cell. This solution is based off of a custom cell.